# HTML form fields not usable in chrome, works in IE

Tags: html, css

The admin login form for the website I'm building isn't working in chrome, but it works fine in IE. What could be causing this? I found one other question on here about a similar issue, but its answers didn't work for me.

Preview: http://a.emutek.net/site/admin/

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
        <div class="divhead" id="adminhead">Login to website management:</div>
        <div id="adminlogin">
            <form name="adminlogon" action="login.do.php" method="post">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Username: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="user">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="pwd">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #body {
        z-index: -1;
        position: relative;
        top: -6px;
        padding: 7px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 6px;
}

.divhead{
    background-color: #111;
    color: #CCC;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#head{
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image:url('../img/bg_header.png');   
}
#adminlogin{
    margin-left: 40%;
    z-index: 10;


}
#adminhead{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: remove your z-index from body in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the  `position: relative;` in `#body` it will work

you can see the cursor its in chrome also tested in firefox and safari

[image]

Comment: Ahh! thank you :) Do you mind elaborating on why it did this?

Comment: @Jeremy yours very welcome check http://css-class.com/test/css/visformatting/layers/z-index.htm and http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/29/an-indepth-coverage-on-css-layers-z-index-relative-and-absolute-positioning/ there  are very good .. and you will  understand more easily and effective

Answer (score 1):

Instead of positioning `#body` to get it below `#nav`, you should position `#nav` to be above `#body`.

#body{
    <s>position: relative;
    z-index: -1;</s>
    ...
}

```css
#nav{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your z index css in the body from -1 to something positive

```
body {
    z-index: 1111;
}
```